navigation compose java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No static method composable
I have problem in my HomeRegisterer class. I didn't understand where the problem in my HomeRegisterer class
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.navigationexamples, PID: 6436
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No static method composable$default(Landroidx/navigation/NavGraphBuilder;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/util/List;Ljava/util/List;Lkotlin/jvm/functions/Function1;Lkotlin/jvm/functions/Function1;Lkotlin/jvm/functions/Function1;Lkotlin/jvm/functions/Function1;Lkotlin/jvm/functions/Function2;ILjava/lang/Object;)V in class Landroidx/navigation/compose/NavGraphBuilderKt; or its super classes (declaration of 'androidx.navigation.compose.NavGraphBuilderKt' appears in /data/data/com.example.navigationexamples/code_cache/.overlay/base.apk/classes9.dex)
at com.example.home.HomeNavRegisterer.registerGraph(HomeNavRegisterer.kt:11)
at com.example.navigationexamples.NavHostKt$NavGraph$1.invoke(NavHost.kt:14)
at com.example.navigationexamples.NavHostKt$NavGraph$1.invoke(NavHost.kt:13)
at androidx.navigation.compose.NavHostKt.NavHost(NavHost.kt:390)
at com.example.navigationexamples.NavHostKt.NavGraph(NavHost.kt:13)
at com.example.navigationexamples.MainActivity$onCreate$1$1.invoke(MainActivity.kt:31)
interface NavigationRegisterer {
    fun registerGraph(navController : NavHostController, navGraphBuilder: NavGraphBuilder)
}

class HomeNavRegisterer : NavigationRegisterer {
    override fun registerGraph(navController: NavHostController, navGraphBuilder: NavGraphBuilder) {
        navGraphBuilder.composable(Screens.HomeScreen.route) {
            HomeScreen()
        }
    }
}


interface NavStarter {
    fun startHomeScreen() : NavigationRegisterer
}

class NavStarterImpl: NavStarter{
    override fun startHomeScreen(): NavigationRegisterer {
        return HomeNavRegisterer()
    }
}



@Module
@InstallIn(SingletonComponent::class)
object NavModule {

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun provideStarter(): NavStarter {
        return NavStarterImpl()
    }
}



@Composable
fun NavGraph(navController: NavHostController, starterImpl: NavStarter) {
    NavHost(navController = navController, startDestination = Screens.HomeScreen.route ) {
        starterImpl.startHomeScreen().registerGraph(navController = navController, navGraphBuilder = this)
    }
}

@AndroidEntryPoint
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    @Inject
    lateinit var starter : NavStarter
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        enableEdgeToEdge()
        setContent {
            NavigationExamplesTheme {
                val navController = rememberNavController()
                NavGraph(navController = navController, starterImpl = starter)
            }
        }
    }


How can I solve this problem? Thanks in advance for your helping

Can you post full stack trace?

I posted full stack trace
